# Windows Media Player crashes on startup after CPU upgrade

Tags: windows-vista, cpu, windows-media-player, drm

I upgraded my CPU, reactivated Windows Vista etc.

But WMP has stopped working. It just crashes almost immediately after starting up.

If I look in Event Viewer it mentions the source as being "Indiv01.key". I have searched my OS drive for this file but it does not exist anywhere.

Some Googling has revealed it seems to be a common problem and that it is DRM related. Though there doesn't seem to be any concrete solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used Sysinternals Process Monitor and determined there are some hidden operating system files located at:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DRM\Cache

I turned off the "Hide protected operating system files" check box on Folder Options so that they would show up.

I simply deleted these files (OK, for safety I first copied them to a temporary location).

Then WMP immediately sprung back to life. No more crashes. I can see WMP has regenerated some of the files that were there again.

Comment: Seriously. People use WMP? :))

Answer (score 0):

If (and it's a big "if") the DRM is tied to the CPU somehow then changing the CPU could break it.

Have you tried uninstalling and then re-installing Windows Media Player? This should detect the new CPU and install the correct files etc.

I'd try this anyway (or at least a "repair" if that's available on the installer).